# JPA Id egeneration.AUTO results in NULL?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I keep getting contraint violation, for my id is null and row in the table could not insert,

SQLEXCEPTION  cannot insert null into column id

my id in the tbale has the following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
```

im using SQL Server.... any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sorted it out, apparently someone had deleted the auto increment and changed the identity column to a normal int column.

fixed in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
@Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
```

Answer (score -1):

try modifying @Column to 
@Column( nullable = false, name="id" )

Comment: nope still does not work.. do you think it could be Database?.. corruptd or something...?

Comment: Is it happening only on one table ! Are you using Hibernate ?

Comment: yes its only happening on one table and im using hibernate, but i didnt want to put any specific hibernate annoations on my entities. If i can help it...

Comment: @user1555190 then how are going to map class fields with table columns?

Comment: No i meant im using javax.persistence..XXX ... I didnt want to use hibernate specifics..